# backBarButtonItem, leftBarButtonItem nil, but hidesBackButton working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

after viewDidLoad()

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;

self.parentViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
```

**are all nil**, but i see the back button and when is use

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

it hides the back button! i just want to disable the back button (with setEnabled:), not hide it!

Answer (score 0):

ok, no matter what you do, you cant access the original back button... the only way to do so, is to create your own